# PHP parse error, unexpected '[' on empty array

Tags: php, syntax

I'm trying to install OpenDocman, and am getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in blablahblah/TemplateRegistry.php on line 156
```

The line in question reads:

```
$this->found = [];
```

Which suggests to me that my version of php (5.3.29) doesn't like this syntax.  I'm assuming that the intent is to set 'found' to an empty array.

What's the best way to tackle this please?

Comment: Upgrade your php?!

Comment: upgrade your php or use array();

Comment: install php 5.4 or higher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short syntax for [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) was added to `PHP5.4`.

You have to possibilites of fixing this:

**Updating PHP**

Install a newer version of PHP, for this function you need atleast `PHP5.4`. Help on upgrading to newer versions can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php

**Old array syntax**

You can use the old array syntax:

```
$this->found = array();
```

Answer (score 2):

in php 5.3 or less will not support python or java-script like array's ( []  )

So you have to use 5.4+ to use this feature.

But now use array() instead of []

read [PHP manual for arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

With php 5.3, you can used $this->found =array()